# yixing teapot Mark translation please

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I puchased this teapot and believe it to be Yixing but I would like to see if I can find out when it was made or the artist.

[image: mark]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is trying to say

[image: 万菊芬制]

> Crafted by 「万菊芬」 (Mandarin Pinyin: **Wàn Júfēn**)

If you Google image search 「万菊芬制」 you'll get lots of pictures of teapots pointing to the same craftswoman. However, the shape of that 「万」 doesn't look quite right to me, so I'm not sure about the authenticity of your item.

---

The following is an image of a seal on the bottom of a 「万菊芬」 teapot, from https://www.taobao.com/list/item/602577735405.htm?spm=a21wu.10013406.taglist-content.5.75eb2019RXl9UK

[image: 萬菊芬]

The seal is styled as 「萬菊芬」 (rather than 「万菊芬制」 as on your image); note the orthodox character form 「萬」 as opposed to 「万」.